# BigQuery Node.js api to create external table

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create an external table from a google cloud function using the node.js API. The function will trigger from GCS bucket changes. I can create a native table but not an external table. In the node.js api for import [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/google-cloud/0.49.0/bigquery/table?method=import), the configuration.load metadata does not have a setting to specify this as external table. Here is my code for native table creation till now. My question is "How do I use the Node.js Api to create external table for a GCS bucket"

```
    const projectId = "N"
    const bigquery = BigQuery({
        projectId: projectId
    });
    const storage = Storage({
        projectId: projectId
    });

    const dataset = bigquery.dataset("dataset");

    const table = dataset.table("test_data");

    const bucket = storage.bucket("my-bucket");

    const file = bucket.file("2017/03/02/*");

    let job;

    // Imports data from a GCS file into a table
    return table.import(file,{"sourceFormat":"AVRO"})
        .then((results) => {
            job = results[0];
            console.log(`Job ${job.id} started.`);
            return job.promise();
        })
        .then((results) => {
            console.log(`Job ${job.id} completed.`);
            return results;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution after reading the docs a bit. Federated tables don't work by loading/importing them. They are just tabled with externalConfig set. So this code worked for me

```
const dataset = bigquery.dataset("dataset");
var options = {
    "externalDataConfiguration": {
        "sourceUris": ["gs://my-bucket/2017/03/20/*"],
        "sourceFormat": "AVRO",
        "maxBadRecords": 0,
        "autodetect": true
    }
}
dataset.createTable("test_data_20170320",options, function(err, table, apiResponse){
    console.log(err)
    console.log(table)
    console.log(apiResponse)
})
```

Comment: Hi Ram, i'm trying solve the same thing with Ruby code, I'm not sure if you know ruby but if you have any pointers it would be appreciated, my question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433598/api-config-for-bigquery-federated-data-source