# API config for BigQuery Federated Data Source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have the following config that works fine for loading a bunch of files into BigQuery:

```
config= {
  'configuration'=> {
    'load'=> {
      'sourceUris'=> 'gs://my_bucket/my_files_*',
      'schema'=> {
        'fields'=> fields_array
      },
      'schemaUpdateOptions' => [{ 'ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION'=> true}],  
      'destinationTable'=> {
        'projectId'=> 'my_project',
        'datasetId'=> 'my_dataset',
        'tableId'=> 'my_table'
      },
      'sourceFormat' => 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
      'createDisposition' => 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
      'writeDisposition' => 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
      'maxBadRecords'=> 0,
    }
  },
}
```

This is then executed with the following where `client` is pre-initialised:

```
result = client.execute(
  api_method: big_query.jobs.insert,
  parameters: { projectId: 'my_project', datasetId: 'my_dataset' },
  body_object: config
)
```

I am now trying to write the equivalent to create an [external / federated data source](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources) instead of loading the data. I need to do this to effectively create staging tables for ETL purposes. I have successfully done this using the BigQuery UI but need to run in code as it will eventually be a daily automated process. I've having a bit of trouble with the API docs and can't find any good examples to refer to. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone attempting the same, here's what I used to get it working. There are not many working examples online and the docs take some deciphering, so hope this helps someone else!

```
config= {
  "kind": "bigquery#table",
  "tableReference": {
    "projectId": 'my_project',
    "datasetId": 'my_dataset',
    "tableId": 'my_table'
  },
  "externalDataConfiguration": {
    "autodetect": true,
    "sourceUris": ['gs://my_bucket/my_files_*'],
    'sourceFormat' => 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
    'maxBadRecords'=> 10,
  }
}
```

The documentation for `externalDataConfiguration` can be found in the BigQuery [REST API reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#resource) and ["Try this API"](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/insert#try-it) section for `bigquery.tables.insert`.

Then as pointed out in Hua Zhang's answer you run `bigquery.tables.insert` instead of `bigquery.jobs.insert`

```
result = client.execute(
    api_method: big_query.tables.insert,
    parameters: { projectId: my_project, datasetId: my_dataset },
    body_object: config
)
```

Comment: `writeDisposition` and `createDisposition` are only used for load/copy/query jobs which modify permanent BigQuery tables and wouldn't make much sense for an External Data Source. In fact they don't appear neither in the [REST API reference][https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#resource] nor in ["Try this API" section](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/insert) for `externalDataConfiguration`.

Answer (score 2):

By creating an external data source, do you mean create a table that refers to an external data source? In this case you can use bigquery.tables.insert and fill out the [externalDataConfiguraiton](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#externalDataConfiguration). The table can then be used in queries to read from the external data source.

If you only want to use the external data source in one query, you can attach a temporary external table with the query, by putting the table definition to [tableDefinitions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.tableDefinitions). In command line it looks like this:

`bq query --external_table_definition=avroTable::AVRO=gs://path-to-avro 'SELECT * FROM avroTable'`

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that Hua Zhang. Your pointer to `bigquery.tables.insert` put me on the right path, I was still trying to run `bigquery.jobs.insert`. The config took a little trial and error to get right, but I now have it working!

Comment: Good to know you got it working. Mind mark it as answer? :)

Answer (score 2):

## Use idiomatic Cloud libraries when possible

Use the BigQuery module in the [idiomatic Ruby client](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby) for GCP, which is Generally Available, instead of [google-api-ruby-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client), which is both in "maintenance mode only" and "alpha". You can find this recommendation [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client#user-content-working-with-google-cloud-platform-apis) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-ruby).

## Authentication:

You can define project and access using [environment variables](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.51.1/guides/authentication).

## How to create an External Data Source object

This is [an example](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/#/docs/google-cloud-bigquery/v1.1.0/google/cloud/bigquery/project?method=external-instance) of creating an External Data Source with `bigquery.external`. I have slightly modified it to add relevant configurations from your solution.

```
bigquery = Google::Cloud::Bigquery.new

json_url = "gs://my_bucket/my_files_*"
json_table = bigquery.external csv_url do |json|
  json.autodetect = true
  json.format = "json"
  json.max_bad_records = 10
end
```

The object configuration methods are [here](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/#/docs/google-cloud-bigquery/v1.1.0/google/cloud/bigquery/external/datasource). For example: `autodetect`, `max_bad_records`, `urls`, etc.

## How to query it:

```
data = bigquery.query "SELECT * FROM my_ext_table",
                      external: { my_ext_table: json_table }

data.each do |row|
  puts row[:name]
end
```

**Note:** Also, both `writeDisposition` and `createDisposition` are only used for load/copy/query jobs which modify permanent BigQuery tables and wouldn't make much sense for an External Data Source. In fact they don't appear neither in the [REST API reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#resource) nor in ["Try this API" section](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/insert) for `externalDataConfiguration`.